# xcode - compare result of NSDictionary object with integer

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

i have simple question about how to compare result of NSDictionary with integer 
i print on log the data in key result  its equal 0

log

2014-09-17 10:25:42.848 School Link Version 2[1027:60b] the result are 0

but when i compare it , its dosnt work 
i wish know why , its simple compare

```
-(void) didFinish:(NSMutableData *)data{


    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
    NSLog(@"the result are %@",json[@"result"]);
    if (json[@"result"] == 0) {
        [[self _delegate] didFailWithMessage:json[@"message"]];
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You compare string to int, you need to convert string value to int:

```
if ([json[@"result"] intValue] == 0) {
```

Answer (score 2):

First, your code will crash if the server didn't give you a dictionary, but an array. Since it is out of your control what the server sends, your app can crash at any time. You can check that you received a dictionary by writing

```
if (! [json isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) { /* Handle error */ }
```

Once you know it's a dictionary, you need to check what kind of item you actually expect. Do you expect a string, an integer, a decimal number? You should have a spec for the JSON data. If you are not sure, or want to be flexible, both strings and numbers produce an object that will support messages like "doubleValue", "integerValue" etc. Extract the item and assign it to a pointer of a class supporting "doubleValue", for example.

```
NSString* result = json [@"result"];
if (! [result respondsToSelector:@selector (doubleValue)]) { /* Handle error */ }
```

Now you can check whether the doubleValue is equal to 0.

```
if ([result doubleValue] == 0.0) { ... }
```

intValue will fail if the value is a large integer.

integerValue is slightly better but will fail if the value is for example the number 0.3 or the string "0.3". Everything will fail if the result is a string with the contents "Hello". You also should figure out what you want to do if result == nil (there was no key "result") or if result == [NSNull null] (there was a key:value pair "result": null)

The code that you actually wrote compared the object stored at the key "result" with 0, that is with a nil pointer. The object will be nil if the JSON data doesn't contain anything under that key. For example,

```
if (json [@"RandomNonsenseKey"] == 0)
```

will most likely succeed (unless your server sent data with a key RandomNonsenseKey).